# Space Complexity for Reversing Bits

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, space-complexity

What is the space complexity for this solution? This code reverses the bits of a 32 bit unsigned integer. I am unsure as to whether the space is O(N) because a copy all bits are made before returning the answer, or if this is considered O(1) since the size of the answer is not dependent on the size of the input A.

```
unsigned int Solution::reverse(unsigned int A) {
  unsigned int ans = 0;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 32 ; ++i) {
      if (A & (1 << i)) {
          ans += (1 << (31-i));
      }
  }
  return ans;
}
```

Comment: If `A` was 64 bits how would the space used change?  In my opinion it would double so `O(n)` seems appropriate.  If you never change the input size then `O(1)` for 32 bit input.

Comment: This is meaningless, without more information. It constant complexity, for a single value. If this is called for `N` values, this is obviously linear complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we try to analyze line by line your code :

```
unsigned int Solution::reverse(unsigned int A) {
    unsigned int ans = 0;                        // O(1)
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 32 ; ++i) {     // O(1)
        if (A & (1 << i)) {                      // O(1)
            ans += (1 << (31-i));                // O(1)
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Every operation you make is linear. It does not depend on any parameter you give since an unsigned int has a fixed size. According to me, your method is in O(1).

If I may suggest : you should avoid harcoding the value 32 in your code and replace it with `sizeof(A)*8` which should be more portable. `sizeof()` return the size in byte of an object. More information [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof).

Answer (score 1):

Your function takes only unsigned int so, algorithm is bounded by sizeof (unsigned int), so its always the same, so O(1).